# Могу ли я передать массив обьектов с файлами в post запрос на сервер

Tags: json, api, mongodb, nestjs, next

Смогу ли я передать альбом треков(в моем случае) на сервер, нужно ли использовать FormData?
Структура обьекта в формате JSON:

```
{
    name: '',
    artist: '',
    picture: `Тут файл`,
    tracks: [
        name: '',
        artist: '',
        text: '',
        picture: `Тут файл`,
        audio: `Тут файл`,
    ]
}
```

Клиент - Next JS, Сервер - Nest JS, База данных - Mongo DB.

Comment: Если есть файлы - `FormData`. Все остальное тоже в нее...